# Number Format Patterns for Currency

Tags: flutter, dart, number-formatting, intl, currency-formatting

i'd made this currency pattern to prefix a sign (+ or -) based on the value

```dart
static final String _currencyWithPrefixSignAndSymbol = "+ \u00A4 0.00 ;- \u00A4 0.00";
```

the pattern put a + prefix if the value is positive and a - if negative;

**Problem:** i need to remove these signs when the value is 0, is there a way to do this in the pattern ? without doing something like a string.Replace at the final?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an option.
Since Dart 2.7 you can create extensions.
So you can create `num` extension like this:

```
extension MyCurrencyFormat on num {
  static final _currencyWithPrefixSignAndSymbol = NumberFormat("+ \u00A4 0.00;- \u00A4 0.00");
  static final _currencyZero = NumberFormat("  \u00A4 0.00");

  String toCurrencyFormat() {
    return this == 0 ? _currencyZero.format(this) : _currencyWithPrefixSignAndSymbol.format(this);
  }
}
```

and then use it in code in that way:

```
var str1 = 42.toCurrencyFormat(); //  + USD 42.00
var str2 = 0.toCurrencyFormat();  //  USD 0.00
```

Comment: thanks man, this is so cool, i didnt know about this extension